# Hot Deployment using Drools + Guvnor

Tags: loading, drools

I have an Application which is Based on Spring+ Hibernate + Drools. It has static *.drl files. My Question is
1 ) How can i wrap the rules with Guvnor UI ?
2) Is it possible that if a user changes any rule, without redeployment we can use it or fire it. If yes than from what path should i pick my rule ?

My main aim is to keep Rule+ Guvnor in a single module , and the Application which uses and fires rule as different module. So on the fly i can change the rule in Guvnor and it get reflected in the Application ?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can import the rules into Guvnor. Create a new package, select that you want to import from a DRL file. This expects just one file. If you want to import in separate files, pick one and you can add the rest of the DRL rules as technical rules later. Or you can merge the DRL files before importing.

2) Check the documentation for KnowledgeAgent. KnowledgeAgent polls Guvnor for changes in the knowledge packages and helps you update the rules in the module that you want to use for firing the rules. You still need to compile the packages in Guvnor.